# jQuery: can't select link

Tags: jquery, wordpress, upload, media

I'm trying to use wordpress' media upload popup in a custom plugin I'm working on.

So far everything worked, I was able to upload images and insert them into a field, but I have another field that requires a link to the uploaded pdf.

```
tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true;height=200');
window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
    console.log(html);

    console.log(jQuery('a', html));
    console.log(jQuery('a', html).attr('href'));

    console.log(jQuery('img', html));
    console.log(jQuery('img', html).attr('src'));

    imgurl = jQuery('a', html).attr('href');
    current_upload.prev().val(imgurl);

    tb_remove();
}
```

For an image this would be my output, which is right since it's able to select the image source

```
<a href="http://to.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Screen-Shot-2012-06-20-at-12.15.52-PM.png"><img src="http://to.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Screen-Shot-2012-06-20-at-12.15.52-PM-300x221.png" alt="" title="Screen Shot 2012-06-20 at 12.15.52 PM" width="300" height="221" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-49" /></a> to.js:54
[]
undefined
[
    <img src=​"http:​/​/​to.local/​wp-content/​uploads/​2012/​07/​Screen-Shot-2012-06-20-at-12.15.52-PM-300x221.png" alt title=​"Screen Shot 2012-06-20 at 12.15.52 PM" width=​"300" height=​"221" class=​"alignnone size-medium wp-image-49">​
]
http://to.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Screen-Shot-2012-06-20-at-12.15.52-PM-300x221.png
```

But when I select a PDF I get this:

```
<a href='http://to.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/01-Mobile-Characteristics-and-Interaction-Design-Principles-Slides2.pdf'>01 Mobile Characteristics and Interaction Design Principles (Slides)</a> to.js:54
[]
undefined
[]
undefined
```

So I can't figure out why jQuery('img', html) works fine while jQuery('a', html) doesn't, while in both cases there is a link in the returned html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `html = jQuery('<a href="http://to.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Screen-Shot-2012-06-20-at-12.15.52-PM.png"><img src="http://to.local/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Screen-Shot-2012-06-20-at-12.15.52-PM-300x221.png" alt="" title="Screen Shot 2012-06-20 at 12.15.52 PM" width="300" height="221" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-49" /></a>');`, `html` *is* the `<a>` element.

`jQuery('a', html)` tries to select `<a>` within the children of `html`, which returns no results as there are no `<a>` elements there.

Since `<img>` is a children of the `<a>` parent in `html`, `jQuery('img', html)` works.

In your case, to get the `href` attribute of `html`, do this:

```
jQuery(html).attr("href")
```

(Remove the `jQuery()` if `html` is already an jQuery object)

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense, I was a little confused about it, but knowing that the <a> was the actual html clears it up.

Answer (score 2):

The html itself is an "a".

```
console.log(jQuery(html).attr('href'));
```